# BluetoothGattDescriptor is NULL for Beacon device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, beacon

BluetoothGattDescriptor is NULL for this [Beacon device](http://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Indoor-positioning-Bluetooth-4-0-Low-Energy-iBeacon-iBeacon-module-with-UUID-Major-and-Minor/32309607597.html?spm=2114.03020208.3.53.VnXEh9&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_4_79_78_77_80,searchweb201644_0,searchweb201560_9)

[image]

here is my code:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))
                            .getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")); // HERE descriptor = NULL
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(desc);


        characteristic.setValue("newName".getBytes());
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

**Why descriptor is NULL?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, it was because some devices (mine is Samsung E5) are support BLE but doesn't support BluetoothGattDescriptor [0x2902](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/descriptors/Pages/DescriptorsHomePage.aspx) (see link)

to see all Descriptors which are supporter in your device call this:

```
for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor:characteristic.getDescriptors()){
                    Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothGattDescriptor: "+descriptor.getUuid().toString());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, it shouldn't be null unless the characteristic does not have notification property. Are you sure that the remote device added *Characteristic Client Config Descriptor* to its GATT table for this particular characteristic? Just to double check it do the following: Put a break point where the services are discovered and find the characteristic in debugger. Find characteristic properties and see if characteristic property has this value: `PROPERTY_NOTIFY`

> Constant Value: 16 (0x00000010)

Alternatively, log the property value: `characteristic.getProperties ()`